# Using the undocumented "Suggested Edit Link" magic column displays "[object Object]"

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Queries that use the undocumented magic column for suggested edits (Suggested Edit Link) break; they display `[object Object]` instead of the suggested edit ID, let alone a direct link to the suggested edit.

An example is this popular query: [**Suggested edits on my stuff**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/49109/suggested-edits-on-my-stuff).

It really seems to be the magic column name that's causing this; [calling the ID anything other than that](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61169) works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just weren't believing hard enough in the magic that the column needed to use to render the link correctly.

That said, I've now gone ahead and [made sure it just works](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=f7343bfbf64796d7e391d0d7f64dd64b82acf9f1) anyway (pending waffles' approval and deploy).